# Salesforce Github Actions

Tags: github, salesforce, devops, github-actions

can we configure our github actions yml file such that whenever we make commit to our repository, it automatically prepares the empty package.xml file with the components commited and deployment begins to the target org?

I know how its done when we have packaged.xml file along with the componets in it,but here the package.xml file should be empty and whenever we commit our changes to the repository, yml automatically prepares the components to be deployed based on the commits in the empty package.xml file and then finally deploys to the org

Answer (score 0):

For triggering event you'll need to define "on" in the yml. You can start with what's in https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml - on any commit/pull request to main branch unless it's just a readme change. And allows for manual triggering too

```
on:
    workflow_dispatch:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
        paths-ignore:
            - 'sfdx-project.json'
            - 'README.md'
```

As for actual commands...

What's your Github repository's format? Old school metadata api format (with package.xml, Account.object containing dozens of fields, listviews, validation rules) or new source tracking format (Account is a folder, every single field gets its own small xml file, most important directory is probably "force-app/main/default")?

You should be able to call `sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi` in your github action to create a temp directory called "mdapi". If you're making a managed package read up about the "-n" option. It will contain your changes but converted from source to mdapi format.

There are things it will not do that [a hand-crafted package.xml would](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm) (description, post install class) - but again, these tend matter when you make managed packages, for normal usage you should be fine.

After convert try `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi -l RunLocalTests -w -1 -c` (metadata format deploy, which directory, which tests, wait as long as it's needed, just validate, don't really deploy)

There are sfdx plugins to make it smarter (deploy a delta between 2 commits, not a full project every time). https://wiki.sfxd.org/books/sfdc-tools/page/notable-sfdx-plugins-and-resources

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'll try what you have told above. My project is based on mdapi format.

Comment: mdapi but without package.xml? Strange, how do you work locally, sfdx doesn't complain about missing file? Or you use the org browser in vscode for everything? You could try converting to source and back maybe. Try with sfdx commands locally and once you have it working - make github action out of it.

Comment: So basically we want a way to do delta deployement with mdapi format.We want to have a package.xml sort of file apart from the normal package.xml file which is empty initially and whenever we commit something on the repository, the yml prepares this empty package.xml with the components which have got changes in them and starts deployment. This is being done so as to do delta deployement.

Comment: Check plugins from that wiki I linked, maybe https://github.com/callawaycloud/sfdx-git-packager ?